# Xml etree iterate subchild based on attribute and write to dictionary

Tags: python, elementtree

[image]

I have a scenerio in which I have a subchild element Source in which there are 3 sources and inside each source I have SOURCEFIELD and its own atrributes. I want to get the results of the PARTICULAR sourcefields based on the _NAME attribute of the source

part of XML:

```
<SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATABASETYPE ="Netezza" DBDNAME ="SHEDW_CORE" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP" OBJECTVERSION ="1" OWNERNAME ="ADMIN" VERSIONNUMBER ="1">
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="numeric" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="1" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="14" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="DIM_CUSTOMER_SQN" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="0" PHYSICALLENGTH ="12" PHYSICALOFFSET ="0" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="12" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="timestamp" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="2" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="19" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="LOAD_END_DATE" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="14" PHYSICALLENGTH ="26" PHYSICALOFFSET ="12" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="26" SCALE ="6" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
    </SOURCE>
    <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATABASETYPE ="Netezza" DBDNAME ="SHEDW_CORE" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="SAT_CONTACT" OBJECTVERSION ="1" OWNERNAME ="ADMIN" VERSIONNUMBER ="1">
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="numeric" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="1" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="PRIMARY KEY" LENGTH ="14" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="SAT_CONTACT_SQN" NULLABLE ="NOTNULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="0" PHYSICALLENGTH ="12" PHYSICALOFFSET ="0" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="12" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="numeric" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="2" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="14" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="CONTACT_SQN" NULLABLE ="NOTNULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="14" PHYSICALLENGTH ="12" PHYSICALOFFSET ="12" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="12" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="timestamp" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="3" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="19" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="LOAD_DATE" NULLABLE ="NOTNULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="28" PHYSICALLENGTH ="26" PHYSICALOFFSET ="24" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="26" SCALE ="6" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="timestamp" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="4" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="19" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="LOAD_END_DATE" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="47" PHYSICALLENGTH ="26" PHYSICALOFFSET ="50" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="26" SCALE ="6" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="varchar" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="5" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="0" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="REC_SOURCE" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="66" PHYSICALLENGTH ="30" PHYSICALOFFSET ="76" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="30" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        </SOURCE>
```

The code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

if not ET.parse('C:\\Desktop\\xml\\m_DM_DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER.xml'):
    raise SyntaxError
else:
   print("The XML is valid")
   tree = ET.parse('C:\\Desktop\\xml\\m_DM_DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER.xml')
   root = tree.getroot()][1]][1]

dd = []
for source in root.iter('SOURCE'):
    print("\n")
    sourcename = source.attrib['NAME']

    print("*********** The DETAILS of  SOURCE: %s: : ***********" %sourcename)
    print(source.attrib)
    print("*********** The COLUMN NAMES of  SOURCE: %s ***********" % sourcename)
    for sourcefields in source.iter("SOURCEFIELD"):
        print(sourcefields.attrib)
        dd.append(sourcefields.attrib)
        dict[sourcename] = dd



Expecting output as:
{
NAME1:[{Sourcefields}],
NAME2:[{Sourcefields}],
NAME3:[{Sourcefields}]
}
```

How can we fetch the sourcefields subsubchild based on attributes of source

Comment: Please post XML as text, not as an image.

Comment: The XML is a very big file hence i posted the image

Comment: @mzjn I added a part of xml for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of the {NAME:source.attribute}:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO
from pprint import pprint

xml_ex = """
<root>
    <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATABASETYPE ="Netezza" DBDNAME ="SHEDW_CORE" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP" OBJECTVERSION ="1" OWNERNAME ="ADMIN" VERSIONNUMBER ="1">
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="numeric" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="1" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="14" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="DIM_CUSTOMER_SQN" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="0" PHYSICALLENGTH ="12" PHYSICALOFFSET ="0" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="12" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="timestamp" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="2" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="19" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="LOAD_END_DATE" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="14" PHYSICALLENGTH ="26" PHYSICALOFFSET ="12" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="26" SCALE ="6" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
    </SOURCE>
    <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATABASETYPE ="Netezza" DBDNAME ="SHEDW_CORE" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="SAT_CONTACT" OBJECTVERSION ="1" OWNERNAME ="ADMIN" VERSIONNUMBER ="1">
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="numeric" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="1" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="PRIMARY KEY" LENGTH ="14" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="SAT_CONTACT_SQN" NULLABLE ="NOTNULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="0" PHYSICALLENGTH ="12" PHYSICALOFFSET ="0" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="12" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="numeric" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="2" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="14" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="CONTACT_SQN" NULLABLE ="NOTNULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="14" PHYSICALLENGTH ="12" PHYSICALOFFSET ="12" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="12" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="timestamp" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="3" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="19" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="LOAD_DATE" NULLABLE ="NOTNULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="28" PHYSICALLENGTH ="26" PHYSICALOFFSET ="24" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="26" SCALE ="6" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="timestamp" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="4" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="19" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="LOAD_END_DATE" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="47" PHYSICALLENGTH ="26" PHYSICALOFFSET ="50" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="26" SCALE ="6" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="varchar" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="5" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="0" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="REC_SOURCE" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="66" PHYSICALLENGTH ="30" PHYSICALOFFSET ="76" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="30" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
    </SOURCE>
    <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATABASETYPE ="Netezza" DBDNAME ="SHEDW_CORE" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_OOO" OBJECTVERSION ="1" OWNERNAME ="ADMIN" VERSIONNUMBER ="1">
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="numeric" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="1" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="14" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="DIM_CUSTOMER_SQN" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="0" PHYSICALLENGTH ="12" PHYSICALOFFSET ="0" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="12" SCALE ="0" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="timestamp" DESCRIPTION ="" FIELDNUMBER ="2" FIELDPROPERTY ="0" FIELDTYPE ="ELEMITEM" HIDDEN ="NO" KEYTYPE ="NOT A KEY" LENGTH ="19" LEVEL ="0" NAME ="LOAD_END_DATE" NULLABLE ="NULL" OCCURS ="0" OFFSET ="14" PHYSICALLENGTH ="26" PHYSICALOFFSET ="12" PICTURETEXT ="" PRECISION ="26" SCALE ="6" USAGE_FLAGS =""/>
    </SOURCE>
</root>"""
file = StringIO(xml_ex)

root = ET.parse(file).getroot()

source = root.findall(".//SOURCE[@NAME]")

d = {}
for elem in source:
    for k, v in elem.items():
        d[elem.get('NAME')] = elem.attrib

pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{'DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_OOO': {'BUSINESSNAME': '',
                          'DATABASETYPE': 'Netezza',
                          'DBDNAME': 'SHEDW_CORE',
                          'DESCRIPTION': '',
                          'NAME': 'DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_OOO',
                          'OBJECTVERSION': '1',
                          'OWNERNAME': 'ADMIN',
                          'VERSIONNUMBER': '1'},
 'DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP': {'BUSINESSNAME': '',
                          'DATABASETYPE': 'Netezza',
                          'DBDNAME': 'SHEDW_CORE',
                          'DESCRIPTION': '',
                          'NAME': 'DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP',
                          'OBJECTVERSION': '1',
                          'OWNERNAME': 'ADMIN',
                          'VERSIONNUMBER': '1'},
 'SAT_CONTACT': {'BUSINESSNAME': '',
                 'DATABASETYPE': 'Netezza',
                 'DBDNAME': 'SHEDW_CORE',
                 'DESCRIPTION': '',
                 'NAME': 'SAT_CONTACT',
                 'OBJECTVERSION': '1',
                 'OWNERNAME': 'ADMIN',
                 'VERSIONNUMBER': '1'}}
```